# How to prevent lazy loading in partial views, custom Display/Editor Templates?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-entities, lazy-loading

In my ASP.NET MVC 4 web application, I have utilized partial views and custom display/editor templates to modularize the code. One example is a User.cshtml DisplayTemplate which takes User (an Entity object) and prints out their name and an icon to popup their directory info.

Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/User.cshtml

```cs
@model MyApp.Domain.Entities.User

@if (Model != null) {
  @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.DisplayName)
  <span class="view-contact icon ui-icon ui-icon-contact" title="View Contact"></span>
  @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Identity)
}
```

I'm having the opposite problem most people seem have when I searched on the topic. I've noticed that when I use this template, lazy loading is triggered and so a query is sent to the DB to grab the data, but I don't want this to happen if I've already preloaded the data, especially in the case where I show a listing of users.  In that case I made sure to use .Include("User") in my query and the info displays without issue or additional querying when I essentially write out the template's code in the view:

Simplified excerpt from Views/MyController/List.cshtml

```cs
...

@foreach (var item in Model) {
  <tr>
    <td class="alignl">
      @item.User.DisplayName
      <span class="view-contact icon ui-icon ui-icon-contact" title="View Contact"></span>
      @Html.HiddenFor(m => item.User.Identity)
    </td>
  </tr>
}

...
```

If I replace those three lines with the call to template, each line queries the db.

```cs
@foreach (var item in Model) {
  <tr>
    <td class="alignl">
      @Html.DisplayFor(i => item.User)
    </td>
  </tr>
}
```

How do I utilize this template without triggering a unnecessary query?

Comment: Exactly *when* is lazy loading triggered, and lazy loading of *what*? Do you know you can turn off lazy loading?

Comment: It loads during the foreach loop in the view and it queries the db to return the user from the Users table.  I will look up disabling lazy loading for a single request and give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: @GertArnold thanks for that suggestion.  I didn't end up disabling lazy loading specifically, but it did lead me down a path that produced the desired result.  How can I credit you with helping me find my answer?

Comment: Never mind. It would be great if you could share an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @GertArnold 's suggestion I looked a little closer at the main query that grabs the collection of users and tried to see if I could disable lazy loading. Because I was using a generic repository pattern and unit of work, I wasn't able to specifically disable it just for that call so I ended up using the context directly and everything behaved properly without disabling needed -- this breaks my pattern, but I now have the benefit of being able to use projection and save my application from eagerly loading unnecessary data columns.

If anyone can point me down the right path for implementing projection in a generic repository, I'd be greatful, but I can live with this alternative solution for now.

This msdn article also helped: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx